# A question from the proof of function of the Brownian motion is a martingale.

Tags: probability-theory, brownian-motion, martingales

This is the theorem 7.5.8 in Durrett book.

> If $u(t,x)$ is the polynomial in $x$ and $t$ with  $$ \frac{\partial
>  u}{\partial t}+\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}=0 $$  Then
> $u(t,B_t)$ is a martingale.

Proof: Let $p_t = (2\pi)^{-1/2} t^{-1/2}\exp(-(y-x)^2/2t)$ and $p_t$ satisfies the heat equation:
$$ \frac{\partial
 p_t}{\partial t}+\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2 p_t}{\partial y^2}=0 $$
Then the book proved that $E_x(t,B_t)$ is a constant by showing that $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}E_x(t,B_t)=0$.
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{\partial}{\partial t}E_x(t,B_t)&=& \int \frac{\partial}{\partial t} (p_t(x,y) u(t,y)) dy\\
&=& \int \frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial^2p_t}{\partial y^2}u(t,y)+p_t(x,y)\frac{\partial u(t,y)}{\partial t}\\
&=&0~(Integrating ~by~parts~twice)
\end{eqnarray*}.

I have two questions from this proof.

i) What is the purpose to prove $E_x(t,B_t)$ is a constant?

ii) Why the boundary terms are zero while integrating by parts in the last step?

Can anyone please clarify these two points?

Comment: If you already know Itô's formula, you can apply it to $u$ to discover that $u(t,B_t)$ is driftless, hence a local martingale. Given that $u$ is a polynomial, from there you should be able to argue that $u(t,B_t)$ is in fact a martingale.

Comment: @JoseAvilez I am trying to prove this by using Markov property instead of by using Ito's formula.

Answer (score 1):

Durrett's book is good but full of typos and half proofs. That's why he's already at the fifth edition.

[https://services.math.duke.edu/~rtd/PTE/PTE5_011119.pdf](https://services.math.duke.edu/%7Ertd/PTE/PTE5_011119.pdf)

If you look there (p. 377), it seems that the proof was completed since your copy was printed, answering both your questions.

Comment: Is the author is trying to do the following? for each $t \rightarrow E_{x} u(t,B_{t})$ is constant. So, $E_{B(s)}v(t-s,B_{t-s})=v(0,B_s)$.